# Microsoft Graph - Azure AD Information

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the Tenant ID, Client ID and Cliente Secret of an Azure Active Directory, is it possible to do it using Microsoft Graph?

Comment: Client secrets don't belong to "an Azure Active Directory", they're specific to one client app within the AAD tenant. Secrets also cannot be retrieved at all with any method, other than at the time of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the TenantId from the home page of "Azure Active Directory" that you can find in the search on portal.azure.com

However Client Ids and Client Secrets are App Registration specific and define permissions your app can acquire when useing said credentials.

I suggest you read the Microsoft docs on that topic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts